# How to connect to remote SQL Server from linux container with docker-compose

Tags: c#, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I am running a .NET Core application on a linux container. The application has health check and I can check status from my local machine with `http://localhost:5102/health`, but the health check for SQL Server is down.

I would like to connect to the remote SQL Server from my container but I can't establish a connection.

I added `extra_hosts` where I declare my SQL Server machine. I don't know if I need to use `network_mode` or not ?

This is my `Dockerfile` :

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:7.0 AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80

ENV ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Staging

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:7.0 AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["TranslationManager.csproj", "TranslationManager/"]
RUN dotnet restore "TranslationManager.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/TranslationManager"
RUN dotnet build "TranslationManager.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "TranslationManager.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish /p:UseAppHost=false

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "TranslationManager.dll"]
```

This is my `docker-compose` :

```
version: '3.4'

services:
  tdi.translator.translationmanager:
    environment:
      - ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Staging
      - Kestrel__Endpoints__HTTP__Url=http://0.0.0.0:80
    ports:
      - 5102:5102
    extra_hosts:
      - "DATABASE_SERVER_NAME:192.168.100.186"
```

I'm trying to ping the SQL Server's IP address, but without success.

I'm new in the docker environment and any ideas greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Don’t use an ip to refer to the sql server running in docker

Comment: Ok, but how I resolve the server name ?

Comment: Use `Data Source` from your connection string